# Filter count column Magento Customer Admin grid with filter_condition_callback

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

I've modified the magento customer admin grid in `../app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php` to include total orders, but need to apply a filter, I've been working with filter_condition_callback but can't get it work. Any suggestions?

**Modified Collection:**

```
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sales_flat_order'), 'sales_flat_order.customer_id=e.entity_id', array('order_total' => 'COUNT(customer_id)'));
    $collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
```

**Order Total Column:**

```
        $this->addColumn('order_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'order_total',
        //'filter' => true,
        'sortable' => false,
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_orderTotalFilter'),
    ));
```

**OrderTotalFilter Callback:**

```
    protected function _orderTotalFilter($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('condition = ?', "$value");
//        $query = $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
//        echo $query;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Hi @afuzzyllama, I'm expecting to be able to filter the order_total column in the magento backend, but there is something wrong with my condition in - `$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('order_total = ?', "$value");` the logs show a field not found error.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

it is not about filter_condition_callback function,

Magento grids do not allow group statements. Your pagination and filters are broken because of this.